# getting the row number of a record from the path and URI, using content provider

Tags: database, uri, row, android-contentprovider, record

is there a way to get the row number of a record for a stored image in the android sqlite database using content provider if i have the URI and the path of the image?

For example i have the following two pieces of information:

URI: content://media/external/images/media/pic05.png

path: /mnt/sdcard/pic05.png

there has got to be a function that will return the row number or some way to do this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats a bit strange because the uri for the image should be something of the form: AuthorityString/UriPathIndex/# where # is the row number. And the image should be stored as a blob in one of the columns or to have its fliepath as a column.

Then, for example, after inserting the picture in your content provider, the returned uri would finish with the row number, which could be retrieved with

```
 long row = ContentUris.parseId(uri);
```

And by querying that row you could get the columns of the cursor which would point to your image.